# Twitter Module - Could not obtain a valid token from the Twitter API. Please review the configuration

Tags: social-network

I've tried a lot of things after googling this problem.
I've uncommented the OpenSSl Extension in PHP.Ini, the callback URL's match, I've changed the Twitter URL to https, but I can't get the module to add an account.

Help appreciated.

Ant:-)

Comment: Did you create application in twitter?

Comment: I ended up embedding with Twitter Block......